# Bootstrap modal backdrop show in front of the modal after recent chrome update

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

Chrome version: Version 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Bootstrap: 4.3.1

Recent chrome update has make the modal backdrop show in front of the modal itself.
I have checked is not the issue of z-index, not sure what have cause this.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="aboutUs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aboutUsModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">{{ property.othersPopupTitle | translate: langPreference }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a (click)="tncOnClick()" class="select-wrapper">
                            <label>{{ property.tnc | translate: langPreference }}</label>
                        </a>
                        
                        <a class="select-wrapper" href="{{'tel:'+ contactUs}}" *ngIf="isMobileDevice">
                            <div class="select-icon"></div>
                            <label>{{ property.contactUs | translate: langPreference }}</label>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just update to Chrome 111.0.5563.65, the [modal bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) looks like work Ok (really I don't know if is 4.3.1 or a 4.3.bigger).

Comment: ya, @Eliseo agree with you , i think something wrong from my code affected just not sure is which part of it.

Comment: This chrome bug is also affecting Bootstrap 5.x
We applied the fix suggestion, but it doesn't look great.
FYI, this also affects Edge and Chrome on mobile.

Comment: Hi @TRock, do you have any solution for this or any findings?

Comment: I think this will be the temporary fix first for current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't downgrade bootstrap.
 Just add background to `.modal` and `.modal-backdrop` display to none in your main style file (style.css).
 Don't forget to call the main `style.css` file after the bootstrap file in your `angular.json`.

```
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
.modal-backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @gopinath, thanks for the suggestions, I can use it as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to Chrome extensions. I found out that "Schema Builder for Structured Data" add this rule as *injected stylesheet*:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

Try disable them one by one.